# WordPress Example Code for Blocking Referrer Spam

Tags: htaccess

While looking for a way to block semalt I found this code block in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Combating_Comment_Spam/Denying_Access):

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Via evil-spam-proxy spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer evil-spam-domain.com spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer evil-spam-keyword spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Via pinappleproxy spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer doobu.com spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer poker spammer=yes

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spammer
```

I simply added the following line:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer semalt.com spammer=yes
```

And semalt was blocked.

**My question is** do I even need any of the other lines from the full code block or are are they (as I may be incorrectly assuming) just examples?

In other words can I simply do this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer semalt.com spammer=yes

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spammer
```

Please advise

Comment: It depends which one referrer URL or how many referrer URLs you wnat to block.  Once you know which referrer URL you'd like to block, you can keep them out by adding one or all: